# Assembly Question about swapping half nibbles

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

I am working on a project and I have the following code in Assembly (ASM)

```
//Part #C - Swap half nibbles
    xor ebx,ebx                             //Clears out the staging register
    mov ecx,4
halfnibswap1_loop:                              //Will shift right side into staging register and reverse them
    shr al,1
    rcl bl,1
    loop halfnibswap1_loop
    shl bl,4                                    //Aligns the staging to left to shift them back (in the new reverse order)

    mov ecx,4
halfnibswap2_loop:                              //Will shifts staging back in, swapped
    shl bl,1
    rcl al,1
    loop halfnibswap2_loop

    mov ecx,4
halfnibswap3_loop :                             //Will shift left side into staging register and reverse them
    shl al,1
    rcr bl,1
    loop halfnibswap3_loop
    shr bl,4                                    //Aligns the staging to right to shift them back (in the new reverse order)

    mov ecx,4
halfnibswap4_loop:                              //Will shifts staging back in, swapped
    shr bl,1
    rcr al,1
    loop halfnibswap4_loop
```

I start off with BD (10111101) in al.  What I want is E7 (11100111).
Basically, in the byte 76543210  needs to be 54761032.  (Swapping adjacent pairs of bits.)

My code seems to work, but I don't think it is quite right and DEFINITELY not efficient.  How would I do it correctly?

Comment: Can't you just do something like `((al << 2) & 0xCC) | ((al >> 2) & 0x33)`? That's like 5 or 6 instructions total.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possible implementation in 5 instructions:

```
lea ebx,[eax*4]   ; ebx = eax*4 (i.e. eax << 2): 76543210 -> 543210..
and bl,0xCC       ; 543210.. -> 54..10..
shr al,2          ; al >>= 2: 76543210 -> ..765432
and al,0x33       ; ..765432 -> ..76..32
or al,bl          ; al = 54761032
```

Comment: I was playing around with the concept code of:
mov al,0xBD
mov bl,al
shr al,2
xor al,0x0B
shl bl,2
xor bl,0xB0
or al,bl

Comment: XOR is used when you want to invert certain bits and keep the others. AND is used when you want to keep certain bits and clear the others (which is what we want in this case).

Comment: you are right....  Not sure why I spaced out there....  well look at my first code and apparently I like to bang my head against the wall.  Thank you